# How to invoke while statement multiple times in parallel using xargs max-procs utility

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, do-while, xargs

I have a file called `test.txt` in Linux. The contents are below.

`test.txt`

```
['table1']
['table2']
['table3']
['table4']
['table5']
and so on
```

Now I have a `while` statement that loops over the `test.txt` file does some jobs.

`While` statement is below:

```
while read -r line; do
  table=${line:2:-2}
  validateTable=$(hive --database history -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")
  if [[ -z $validateTable ]]; then
      /home/"$USER"/import.py "${table}"
  else
       /home/"$USER"/append.py "${table}"
  fi
done < < test.txt
```

In this `while` statement `validateTable` is to check whether table is present in `hive` or not.

If not present then it will invoke `import.py` script

if present it will invoke `append.py` script.

Now the while statement works fine. I am getting the expected result.

Requirement:

What I require is this I want to invoke the `while statement` in parallel. I mean I want the `while` to run 10 times at the same time.

What is the best possible solution.

I found that we can do it with `xargs --max-procs` option but cannot figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` requires a single command to run, which means you would need to put the body of the loop into a shell script. Something like (call it `myscript`)

```
#!/bin/bash
table=${1:2:-2}
validateTable=$(hive --database history -e "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")
if [[ -z $validateTable ]]; then
  /home/"$USER"/import.py "${table}"
else
  /home/"$USER"/append.py "${table}"
fi
```

Then run something like

```
xargs --max-procs 10 myscript < test.txt
```

Comment: I have tried your code. It is working only for one table and exiting. It doesn't perform for all tables, even when I use the `xargs --max-porcs 10`

Comment: I got it to work by adding `-n 1` in the xargs statement like `xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 myscript < test.txt`